# Can't update Android Studio - only download

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, updates

I have not updated my Android Studio for a while and am presented with this dialog box when trying to update:
[image]

Usually there is an "update and restart" option, but not here. The only option is "Download" which directs me [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Updating) where I can only download the entire bundle again which gives me a link for Build Number - 130.737825. As you can see that's before what I already have so I don't see how that would fix the problem?

I feel like I'm missing something blaringly obvious, but how can I just update like I have been able to before?

Comment: If you are getting Android Studio update dialog box like this (*version will change*)
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/enEJ8.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/enEJ8.png) <br> visit this SO link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906325/cant-update-android-studio-no-update-and-restart-button/35432954#35432954 Happy_Coding;

Comment: I reported this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38290281). Maybe one day they will fix it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That means that the current version can not be automatically updated. You should download the new version manually.

Comment: Seems this is the only option. If you leave updates for too long you get a version update difference (i.e. 0.2.3 - 0.2.9) which the update system can't provide a patch for. I don't really understand if there's obviously a patch between each consecutive version, they can't be linked together into 'one' patch. But anyway, this is definitely the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Do I have to uninstall the old version in order to install the new version?

Comment: Yes, you will be asked to uninstall.But you will keep all your settings.

Answer (score 28):

I also had same issue. I updated my Android Studio from `1.3` to `1.5`. Just by

> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates

and Update & Restart button was back.

Comment: Just visiting that settings page without actually changing anything fixed it for me too. Weird, but thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on elementary OS (based on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 16):

I was on version `0.4.4` trying to update to `0.5.8`.  At first I thought I would have to do it manually, but I found a workaround.

First I had to update to the latest version in the `dev channel`, which I switched to in the IDE setting under `file -> settings -> updates`.  This allowed me to automatically update to `0.5.2`.  Android Studio then detected the `0.5.8` build and allowed me to update automatically.

YMMV, and so will your versions when you see this, but maybe try not going from a really old version straight to the recent `canary channel` build.

Comment: Your answer is better than the accepted answer. One little issue - I had to follow this path **File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates** to update to the latest version in the `dev channel` in my `version 1.3.2 build-141.2178183`. Thanks :-) from Bangladesh...

Answer (score 4):

I too ran into this problem. I did not want to uninstall and reinstall it again. What I did was to unzip the downloaded file and just copy and replaced the bin, lib, license and plugins folder into my original install path and it worked.

I am on Windows.

Comment: Just copying the new files into the original folder doesn't work. Android Studio will startup, but then flag as corrupted. You need to delete the old files / folder and then copy the latest version into the same path as the old installation.

Comment: @BharatMallapur Yes, that is why I said copy and replace.

Comment: I used your method. What I mean is that copy and replace doesn't work. If you copy and replace, some files are copied in to the folder, which are not there in the original folder. This causes multiple files of one type, which gets flagged by Android Studio as a corruption (it even states that this can happen if you just copy and replace files from the new version into the old version folder). When I DELETED the old files and then copied the new files in, then I faced no problems and Android Studio updated successfully. Still, thanks for suggesting this simple method of updating Android Studio.

Comment: @BharatMallapur - ah ok. Understood. :-)

Comment: Tried it out today again. The exact error message you get if you copy and replace files instead of deleting, then copying is as below: "Your android Studio installation is corrupt and will not work properly.(Found multiple versions of builder-model-*.jar in plugins/android/lib.) This usually happens if Android Studio is extracted into an existing older version. Please reinstall (and make sure the new installation directory is empty first.)

Answer (score 3):

well ,you can go ahead and download the patch and unzip it . In its bin directory run studio64.exe file it will ask to import configuration from older version just click that option and get your newer version running

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

> Go to Help > Check for Update

and this worked for me - `1.0` to `1.1`.

Comment: This has the same issue mentioned in the question

Comment: This doesn't worked for me from version 1.5.1 to 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Check these steps.

1. First you can download latest zip file from the website.
2. Then unzip it Next remove the files inside the Android studio folder.
3. It will contain files same as the file in zip file.
4. Copy the files inside unzip folder and paste it to inside the Android studio folder

Answer (score 2):

If anybody uses Ubuntu and has the same problem....
For me, AS always crashed after the download of a patch was complete. Then I wanted to figure out what's going on by launching AS from the console to see the output (I have AS as icon in Dash menu and usually launch it from there).
After launching AS from console I clicked the update popup again, it downloaded but suddenly, it did not crash anymore. Suddenly it asked me if I want to exit a running background process, I clicked "exit", AS installed the patch and rebooted (what is usually not working either).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you update when you are not presented with a `Update and Restart` button, but instead only have a `Download` button.  The solution involves a side-by-side installation, which is an acceptable and supported configuration<sup>1</sup>

1. **Download the zip file**
2. **Extract the zip file** in the same location folder your previous installation (adjacent to, not overlaying)
   [image: Directory location of unzipped new version]
   Note here that I already had two versions of Android Studio running.  The executables under the `Android Studio` folder, and another set of code under the `android-studio-beta` folder.  The `android-studio-dev` is the folder created from the downloaded zip file.
3. **Start `../bin/studio64.exe`** inside the the unzipped folder and select the appropriate place to pull your configuration from.
   [image: Select configuration location prompt]
   Note that if you are unsure of which configuration is connected to which install, you may examine the `.home` file:
   [image: home file aligns with installation directory]
   Note here that the `AndroidStudioPreview2.2` configuration set is aligned with the installation located at `android-studio-beta`, and not with the installation located at `Android Studio` (the two options shown in step 2).  Wait for the installation to complete, then exit.
4. **Change your start icon** from the previous location to the new location, and restart from the icon.[image: Update Windows launch icon]
5. **Reassert your updates channel** before accepting any update prompts.  As you use your various installations, make sure that your preferred updates channel hasn't changed.  I can't be sure, but it seems like this setting might leak across during installs.  Better safe than sorry.  The image is of my old install, which I did not want to affect by this upgrade.
   [image: Original install to stay on the stable channel]

At some point, probably once you're satisfied that the new installation will work you you, you may remove the previous installation.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Here is an official page to show that it's ok to have side-by-side installs: [Android site multiple installation page](http://tools.android.com/tips/using-multiple-android-studio-versions)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Click remind me later, then run the update process from the running Android Studio (help menu, as far as I remember).

Comment: I tried this and got the same result unfortunately. Seems re-downloading the old version and then installing the update patch on that is the only option...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution without reinstalling the AS!

As the sollution in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56068 goes, We can manually download the patch.

But for examble, if I put the number of current version and newest version in the URL `http://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/AI-(current_version)-(newest_version)-patch-unix.jar`, I got a 404 error, which means there is not a patch between my version and the current version.

At last, I found the solution. For example, the version of my Android Studio is 141.2135290, then I find the version closest to my version (just now is 141.2178183) instead of the newest version "141.2288178", and I got the patch!

But unfortunately, I have modified the file in the folder of Android Studio, so the patch didn't work well, otherwise it will work well.

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer is somewhat wrong. I know It's a little confusing an therefore I'm posting my solution.

Sometimes Android Studio reminds about a new available version for the stable channel but the way to update automatically (as stated in the release info page) is to switch the Channel in your preference:

```
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates
```

and change the setting "Automatically check updates for" to Beta Channel.

Then, perform a Check for updates (or restart your ide) to be prompted with the option to install automatically.

BTW you cannot install upgrades that are totally incompatible with the previous version, but as I'm aware of, the compatibility list is also available on the update page per version release. I.E.: You can upgrade from 1.4/1.5 to 1.5.1, but not from 1.3.

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question the behaviour still exists in latest Android studio (Nov 2020) so an update here:

- A trigger for this seems to be if you have not upgraded in a while and Android has to update from a version which is several versions older than the latest. This makes sense as it might have to otherwise sequentially upgrade through each past version to ensure a safe upgrade.
- Downloading and then installing the new version worked fine for me (Dolphin on a MAC, old version was Artic Fox patch 4).
- During the upgrade the OS asks if you want to replace the old version - I clicked yes.
- The new version installed and automatically imported all my previous versions projects and settings (as far as I can see so far).

It would obviously be nicer if the instructions in Studio could be updated to include notes on this in the update panel as it's clearly still confusing.

It would probably be a good idea to back up your machine before doing to upgrade, just to be safe.

Comment: I have installed Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2 on Windows 11 since a while and just wanted to upgrade to Hedgehog now, but I need to download it. OK, but it comes worse: I need to install it into a new folder, I cannot upgrade Giraffe to Hedgehog. What could be wrong there?

Comment: @franc - I'm assuming you did not get an option to replace the old version as noted above? If not it may be asking a new specific question.

Comment: yes, exactly, the Update Button just opened the Download site to download the Hedgehog. When I installed that, I couldnt use the same folder, a total different install so.

Comment: I think that is worth a new question - maybe you can share the link to it here also to help people with the same issue.

Comment: I am afraid that maybe some misconfiguration on my side could be the culprit and if I ask here, my question could be downvoted because of such...

Comment: OK then, I asked nevertheless: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/255445/android-studio-giraffe-upgrade-to-hedgehog-to-the-same-folder-not-possible