# Can't update Android Studio - no "Update and Restart" button

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

My Android Studio (0.4.3 now) often displays a message that is ready to update, but the alert does not have an "Update and Restart" button:

[image: Update info without "Install" button]

I want to install this update but I don't know how I can do this. After I click the "Remind Me Later" button few times, the fourth button on the left is sometimes visible, allowing me to download and install the update. I haven't discovered any pattern when this button shows up and when it doesn't.

Why isn't it always visible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution for this problem (until they release a fix for it).

1. When Android Studio opens and the update popup shows up without the button, close it with the X button.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open action search dialog, enter **Event Log** and open it.
3. There will be a message telling that *Android Studio is ready to update* and the word *update* is a link that will open a window **with** an *Update and restart* button.

[image]

Answer (score 34):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56737. If you dismiss the dialog and check for updates again, you usually get the button you're looking for. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I didn't find it. However, dismissing and checking for updates again gives the same result.

Comment: I had to dismiss and re-check three times before the dialog appeared correctly, in case anyone else experiences this problem

Comment: Still experiencing this issue, one year later

Comment: In my case clicking on "Ignore this update" and then Help->Check for updates did the trick.

Comment: Yes, I have checked for updates again and again, at last I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Still having this problem 2 years later! Thanks for the answer worked for me too, I thought it seemed absurd that we'd have to download the entire ~2gb installer again

Answer (score 4):

**Actually this issue is kind a bug not really a bug :)**. This is what you need to do

> When an update is available, you'll see a balloon notification in the IDE.
>
> **Two important known issues:**
>   **1.** The first time, you'll see a dialog that asks you to accept this channel. You need to ***press*** "***More info***" to accept this channel, otherwise you won't get notified about updates.
>
> **2.** If you press the "***Ignore This Update***" button, there is currently no mechanism available to revert that decision and Android Studio ***will never tell you about that update ever again***.

For more info. visit : [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel)
below is snap from android tools official site
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on 'ignore updates' and rerunning `Check for updates` for a couple of times did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the button is not available, It might be possible that the version you have currently can't be upgraded to the latest version directly.

In such cases follow the steps mentioned below :

Download the latest OS respective Android Studio as zip(sdk excluded) from here :

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary

- Extract the downloaded Zip file somewhere
- Close Android studio if running.
- Go to current Android Studio installation directory.
- Take a backup(safer side) of that and replace everything except sdk directory
  with the content of extracted Zip file .

This also allows you to update studio in an offline system.

Comment: I'm being presented with a `Download` button instead of of a `Update and Restart` (Going from 2.2 RC to 2.3 Canary). I'd feel better about this process if you provided a link that documents this process.

Comment: If the new version is not supported as the patch update you have to install the complete studio again. This happens when there are some major changes happened on Studio and it won't possible to update as a patch.

Comment: Agreed: sometimes there is no update path and a new install is required. I was asking about an official page that outlined the new install steps, but I didn't find one.  I was able to document my new install, which includes migrating settings from the previous install: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40576343/897007