# Upgrading from Android Studio 1.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.3.1.

After going to Help->Check for updates it says Android Studio 1.5 is available in the stable channel.  However I only have the option to Download this update which takes me to the latest updates pages in the canary channel:

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/

I thought I would be able to download a patch to update from 1.3.1 to 1.5 but it seems like the only option is to download the entire IDE - is this right ?

Comment: "It may not be right, but it is true."

Comment: yup, might as well wait for 2.0.0 :-)

Comment: I've installed the latest version now - 2.0 Preview and imported the settings from 1.3.  It seems to be working ok :)  I also un-installed the old version to save disk space.  The only weird thing is it is unzipped to a totally different location on my hard disk as there was no install wizard in the zip.  I presume it doesn't matter if it isn't installed in program files but would appreciate any thoughts on this?

Comment: visit this [Can't update Android Studio - no “Update and Restart” button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906325/cant-update-android-studio-no-update-and-restart-button/35432954#35432954)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. Because you missed a lot of incremental release and 1.4, IDE doesn't offer delta update option. But don't worry, you will not lose any data after full 1.5 installation.

Comment: Still it would be better to have an offline(downloadable) patch.  Will this continue to be a case of beggars cannot be choosers?