# "Download" button instead of Update and Restart in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to update the android studio and there is no update and restart button instead a download button is there, i searched on the net but no resolution is there. Kindly help[image]

After clicking update, this pops up:

[image]

Comment: can you show me an image after clicking the `Updates` link

Comment: Added the image @Sandy

Comment: once try my answer not sure it will work for you or not but give it a try

Comment: try this [Can't update Android Studio - no “Update and Restart” button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906325/cant-update-android-studio-no-update-and-restart-button/35432954#35432954)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the team making the Android Studio does not provide the patch to update the existing installation of the AS; in these cases the only option to update your IDE is download the fresh version and install it from scratch. Your case is clearly one of those, just hit the `Download` button.

When you run the new version of AS, it'll ask about the previous settings: do you have them or not, and, if you have, do you want to import them or not, giving you the opportunity to import all your preferences and installed plugins.

Comment: but the size of the file is 603mb and AS setup size is 1.1GB...so should i proceed anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Please checked the Automatically check update for the android sdk i am not sure it is working or not but i have faced it before and yes i know it looks weired answer but i have solved that like this only

and then press okay and then try check for updates from studio menu