# How to update Android Studio automatically?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I need to Update Android Studio, to the 0.9.9 version, but when I press "Download" (On the update info dialog box) it sends me here:

> http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Isn't there a way to make the update happen automatically, because I don't even know how to update it manually.

Also, in the dialog, there is this recommendation:

> To configure automatic update settings, see the Updates dialog of your IDE Settings.

The word "Updates" is a link, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update Android Studio - only download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download)

Answer (score 73):

For this task, I recommend using Android Studio IDE and choose the automatic installation program, and not the compressed file.

1. On the top menu, select Help -> Check for Update...
2. Upon the updates dialog below, select **Updates** link to configure your IDE settings.

[image: Platform and Plugin Updates]

3. For checking updates, my suggestion is to select the **Dev** channel. I

> don't recommend Beta or Canary

channel which is the **unstable** version and they are ***not automatic*** installation, instead a zip file is provided in that case.

[image: Updates dialog]

4. When finished with the configuration, select *Update and Restart* for downloading the installation EXE.
5. Run the installation.

Warning: Among different version of Android Studio, the steps may be different. But hopefully you get the idea, as I try to be clear on my intentions.

Extra info: If you want, check for Android Studio updates @ [Android Tools Project Site - Recent Builds](http://tools.android.com/recent). This web page seems to be more accurate than other Android pages about tool updates.

Comment: this worked for me going from 1.3.2 -> 1.4.0. Thanks

Comment: But in my case it is not showing me 'update and start'  button. I am using android studio 1.3 and want to update to latest version that is 1.5 .It is showing me download button that is taking me to the given page 
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/
Any other option to update my version?
and further more I tried as @nktsamba suggested

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, Currently I only have 1.0. I will try the latest at some point in time. If you want the Canary build, only 2.0 is available. In my post, I recommend the Dev or Stable channel. Check which "channel" you selected.

Comment: I have selected stable one.I have 2 machines on my first machine when I updated it showed me update and Restart option.I am wondering it is not showing me the 'Update and Restart' button on my second one.Showing me Download button that leads me to manual downloading.What can be the cause for that? Any help.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, I think you see "Showing me Download" button because the Studio was already updated, if I remember.

Comment: No,this is not the case because as I said I am currently using 1.3 android studio(downloaded from stable channel) and 1.5 is available (in stable channel)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, I reviewed your case. As it says in my post, the Beta or Canary channel does not offer the automatic installation, listed on step 3. I  edited my post to stress that on step 3. It makes sense actually. On unstable builds, Google will just provide you a zip file, nothing more, and you take your risks along with it.  Good luck....

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, There is no Studio 1.5 update in the stable channel, as the web page says on http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable . Version 1.4.1 is the latest for the Stable channel.

Comment: Perhaps this image will clarify Abul Waheed's (and my) issue: 
http://i.snag.gy/ZEhvK.jpg

Comment: @Remian8985, Thanks for the clarification.This web page seems more accurate than other pages. I updated my post reflecting that in the "Extra info". Hopefully this saves/helps other developers.

Comment: I don't have the download button. This is frustrating.

Comment: I had the same issue until I clicked "check for updates now" on the welcome to android screen here: http://imgur.com/UPl1E7E - after that update and restart became available.

Comment: On Windows, if the 'Download and Install' button does not appear, try restarting Android Studio with Run as Administrator.  This made the button appear for me going from 1.5 to 2.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 29):

The simplest way to update is as follows:

1. Go to the start screen for Android Studio. If it automatically opens a project when you open it, close that project (not exit).
2. At the bottom there will be a check for updates link which you can use to update to the latest version.

Comment: +1, I tried checking for updates while I had an project opened. The button "update and restart" didn't show up (More Info, Ignore update, Remind me buttons were shown). Closing the project as you suggested and checking for updates worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Android Studio 2.0 came out this week. I ended up here while searching for how to upgrade from the latest (1.5). The "Check for Updates..." dialog had 3 buttons and none was to actually update.  Amazingly, the dialog that comes up from nktsamba's steps has 4 buttons and one is to patch the current install.  I was just about to give up and install 2.0 atop 1.5, which would have almost certainly caused havok.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that's pretty unintuitive to have to close the project to be able to start the update.

Answer (score 15):

There's not always an updater between versions, depending on the version you're starting from and what you're updating to. If that happens, download the full installer and reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version, when I was done installing it, there was a message saying "There is an update for android studio or something like that".

I might install it manually, but I have no clue.

Comment: Happened to me too today, with version 1.2.1.1 downloaded from their official download page... weird....

Comment: With version 1.2 there is

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted but it was the only right answer in my case. I have Studio version 1.2.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 that I manually downloaded and installed. I've tried every possible solution in this question or in many other sources, but the only button that update manager show me is "download" instead of "update and restart". I've downloaded the full installer of 1.3.2 (last stable version) and reinstalled manually.

Comment: Worth to mention answer

Comment: In this case do we have to uninstall manually the existing studio?

Answer (score 9):

Here's the easiest way, as in snapshot, 
download the required file and install.[image]

Comment: If you have checked the "offline" option under the Gradle settings, to increase your build speed for example, then you will not see the "download" or "update" button .. uncheck this, go to Update, and the update button will show

Comment: Thanks @StevenElliott, I wasn't seeing the Update button...I needed the information you provided.

Comment: "Offline" is not checked. I still only see the "download" button

Answer (score 9):

On the startup screen you can use the configure button to check for updates.

**1)**  Choose configure > Check for Update
[image]

**2)** Download the latest updates

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped me alot

Comment: Download button option available on click of that it's download the new .dmg file instead of update in existing installation 

How we can update studio without downloading new DMG file

Answer (score 8):

Through Android Studio:

1. Help
2. Check for latest update
3. Update

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04 with AS 1.2.1. There's no update option, just download...

Comment: Nor in Mac version - that would be `Android Studio > Check for Updates...`

Answer (score 7):

for windows users
go to **HELP**> **CHECK FOR UPDATES**>**UPDATE**(click the link **updates**)

Answer (score 5):

If you go to help>>check for updates it will tell you if there's an update.

You don't have to change from the stable channel. If you aren't offered an update and restart button, kindly close the window and try again. After about 4 or 5 checks like this, it will eventually show you update and restart button.

Why? because google.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using Android Studio, you can update via the built in Update mechanism (Check For Updates); make sure you switch to the canary or beta channels if you're not being offered an update.

To configure automatic update settings, see the Updates dialog of your IDE Preferences or settings. You can then switch to either the canary or beta channels. (The default is "stable" but probably that one fails to automatically inform of updates).

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: This may be dependent on OS as well.  On OSX 10.10.4, Android Studio 1.3.1 the Studio update dialog box had a button with the text "more info..." instead of "download".  This took me to the website to download and install manually.

Answer (score 2):

I think in the new versions of android studio there is no update and restart when you press check for updates from the android studio, so you have to download the newer version from their official website and install it manually.  First, you have to change the name of the previous setup version folder for Example Android Studio to Android Studio1, and you can now install the newer version and everything will be the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

These steps are for the people who already have Android Studio installed on their Windows machine >>>

Steps to download the update:

1. Google for “Update android studio”
2. Choose the result from “tools.android.com”
3. Download the zip file (it’s around 500 MB).

Steps to install Android Studio from a .zip folder:

1. Open the .zip folder using Windows Explorer.
2. click on 'Extract all' (or 'Extract all files') option in the ribbon.
3. Go to the extract location. And then to **android-studio\bin** and run **studio.exe** ifyou’re on **32bit OS**, or **studio64.exe** if you’re on **64bit OS**.

By then, the Andriod Studio should open and configure your uppdates
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem while updating from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3.

Go to the `bin` folder of your Android Studio installation folder: 
e.g.

```
cd opt/android-studio/bin
```

Provide run permission for studio.sh file:  `chmod +x studio.sh`

Run Android Studio from here: `./studio.sh`

and try `"update and restart"` from android studio.

Answer (score 0):

as of AS 1.2+ there is an auto-check for updates which will let you choose between the stable, dev, canary, and beta channels. However it is just a check instead of a full update script. It does require that you click to install and restart your install ( A problem for a remote server situation)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. There is no built in mechanism for automatically updation of Android Studio. You have to manually download it and configure it.

Comment: Auto updation feature is now coming with Android Studio 1.3 version.

Comment: You can always edit your answer to show that the feature is possible on current versions

Answer (score 0):

MacOS users

```
//Manually
Android Studio -> Check for Updates...

//Check Automatically
Android Studio -> Preferences... -> Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Updates -> Automatically check updates for <channel>

//Check Now
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to be what other answers suggest, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32447872/1364007) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31982496/1364007). I'm not sure that being on MacOS is relevant here.

Comment: Is this solution to do it automatically or manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jet Brains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) to

1. Install
2. Update automatically
3. Update the plugins together with IDE
4. Roll back and downgrade

[jet brains toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)

[image: Jet Brains Toolkit]