# How to update Android Studio manually on OS X? "Check for latest update" option doesn´t exist anymore

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I need to update Android Studio, i have seen that i can do it from the menu:

`Help` > `Check for latest update`

But that option doesn´t exist.

I have checked these questions:

[How to update Android Studio automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133518/how-to-update-android-studio-automatically)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038306/how-to-update-android-studio

Comment: You can always download the newest versions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: @statosdotcom thank you! i have seen that, but i wanted to do from the IDE.

Comment: Not shure but if you "check for updates" too (I'm not on my pc rigth now) the option to update the IDE is showed too. Congrats for your reputation here o.O

Comment: Thank you very much, I have found that now we can update with Android Studio > Check for Updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,now we can do it from:

Android Studio > **`Check for Updates`**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't answer your own question. It's about v1.3 and you say "in later versions we can do this"

Comment: This only works for Mac OS. Linux and windows dont have an 'android studio' menu. Instead, they just have it under the Help menu

Comment: In my experience on mac OS, "Android Studio > Check for Updates" does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IntelliJ Quick Actions.

#### OS X

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

#### Windows / Linux

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

[image: quick actions]