# How I can resolve "This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered"?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, sdk

I am getting this error "This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times."

My app still working but this error is annoying.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It means your tools and out of sync.  Probably the easiest way to fix this is to reinstall Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason for this error can be the usages of **outdated** `Android SDK` tools that are unable to understand the most recent `"SDK XML"` files.

You should update your `SDK tools` to the most recent version that supports the `"SDK XML"`, **Version 3** should solve the problem.

This is a possible procedures to upgrade your `SDK tools`:

1. Open `Android Studio`.
2. Go to `File`->`Settings`->`Appearance & Behaviour`->`System Settings`->`Android SDK`.
3. Open `SDK Manager` and select `SDK Tools`.
4. Check the `Android SDK Built-Tools`.
5. If it's not updated, select the latest version and click `Apply` to install it.
6. When the installation is completed, restart `Android Studio`.
7. Try to `rebuild` your Application.

**You can also try `Invalidate Caches` and to `clone` the project again.**

Also check this [Update the IDE and SDK tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update) and this [sdk - How to update Android Studio automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133518/how-to-update-android-studio-automatically)