Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered
When using flutter emulator, I get

Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

I have done do couple of the solution, but not working at all:

Reinstall android studio and visual studio code. Hard cleaned including the settings. But I do not removed the flutter part in the windows.

Already reinstall the command-line tools and android build-tools in android studio but seems not working at all.

Making sure all the plugin, flutter and dart in latest version


I hope someone can help me go through the problem.

Given that the problem is about different versions, it would really help if you could provide details of the versions of all the tools you're using.

check this answer. Hope it help https://stackoverflow.com/a/75781509/26601193
