# How can I update my android studio 1.2.1.1 to 1.4 beta using patch file?

Tags: android

I am currently using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 now i want to update it so i have downloaded android 1.4 beta patch file(a zip file), as when i checked for update it shows a download button rather than update and restart. Please help me update my android studio.

Comment: Have you tried go into settings and set up updating into canary channel?

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download)