# Android studio 1.2.1.1 - no "update and restart" button

Tags: android

i'm using version 1.2.1.1 and after some weeks of holydays coming back to studio i find the info, that there is a version of about 1.3 stable, but i don't get the "update and restart" - button. Is this such a major update, that i've to download the complete package ? will installing this complete package overwrite my settings ?   thanks   Karl

Comment: It's a big update, but I think I was able to use the built-in updater. Using a complete new Installer download won't delete your settings, it will ask you whether you want to use the old settings or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update Android Studio - only download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download)

Comment: visit this SO [Can't update Android Studio - no "Update and Restart" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open Android Studio -> Help -> Check for update.
I was able to update mine as soon it was released

And no it wont change your settings

Comment: i know  Android Studio -> Help -> Check for update, doesn't work. tomorrow at school i will check my other PC, if it's the same as here. if there's no other way i'll do a complete install. Thanks to all