# How to upgrade Android Studio manually?

Tags: android, android-studio

I got a problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download) post. (I want to update from 0.99 to 1.3).

I downloaded the new Android Studio version, but I am confused if I install the new version of Android Studio is there any problem with the configurations that I done in the old version? Will they be removed or still keep the new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade it manually ,the new version of Android studio will be installed and usually your old version will not be uninstalled.And when the new version start the first time ,it will ask you whether you have installed it before ,and whether you need to import you setting .Now ,you can select to import it .The old settings will not lost.

Answer (score 0):

when you update Android Studio , it change your configurations. for ex : fonts you have set in old version.

but it will ask you to import your old setting

or

you can try this one also.

Just go to your previous .AndroidStudio\config folder, copy and paste them all to the new one (in my scenario I updated from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

On mac you could try from Android Studio => Check For Update [image]