# Unable to update to Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

My current version of Android studio is **1.5** running on **Windows-7**

I tried to update the Android studio to [2.0](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0-preview) which has introduced few useful features. I went to "**Check for Updates**" option in Android studio.

After checking for a update for a while, Android studio returned with below message.

[image]

Now, why Android studio is saying I have a already updated version when I have Android 1.5 only installed and Android studio 2.0 is already Avalilable?

I was connected to Internet while trying to update.

Of course, I can download the whole Android studio 2.0 bundle once again. But why isn't the update from within Android studio is not working?

Do I need to toggle any settings in Android studio or is it the case that the current version can not be automatically updated and I should download the new version manually, as Answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download) StackOverflow post.

**Update:** : Since I was on **Stable** Channel, I was not able to see the updates of Android Studio-2.0 because as of this writing AS-2.0 Updates is only available in **Beta** channel.

I checked the [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0-preview), but it seems that over there, it is mentioned that the update is available in Stable channel.

> The release is available in the stable channel, so you can check for
>   updates via Help > Check for Update.

Comment: Did you check your system configuration @AADTechincal

Comment: yes, after seeing the answer below, I checked the system configuration in Settings > Appearance and Behaviour > System Settings >Updates. My system configuration was pointing to Stable channel and I was under impression that AS-2.0 is available in Stable. It is not, and it is currently available in **beta** Channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are right now on stable channel. Android studio 2.0 is available on the beta channel not in the stable channel. That's why you don't have android studio 2.0 update available.

If you are happy to move in beta channel, go to Settings > Appearance and Behaviour > System Settings >Updates and change to beta channel. Then press check now. You will get AS 2.0 update and update size may vary based on your system.

[image]

Comment: let me try your solution. My intention is to try out new features of AS-2.0, so it does not matter if it is currently in beta channel.

Answer (score 0):

Now Android studio 2.0 is available on the stable channel

If u want to try out latest update  move in canarychannel, go to help-->check for updates and change to canary channel. Then press check now. You will get AS 2.0 update and update size may vary based on your system.

You can also try out the latest emulator that comes with [android Studio 2.0](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.in/2016/04/Android-Studio-installing-and-refrence.html)