# Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I tried to include retrofit library in android studio 2.2.3. I added the following line in gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
```

But it is giving me the following error :

```
Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0.

```
Retrofit requires at minimum Java 7 or Android 2.3.
```

You are not using android studio  **Version 2.3** . Upgrade your Studio version .

**How to check Version .**

```
 File > Settings-> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Updates
```

Comment: Ok, I'll update it. I noticed the requirement of retrofit. But I thought they were talking about android version 2.3.

Comment: Unfortunately getting this weird error while updating :  "Failed to download patch file:
Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/AI-145.3537739-162.4069837-patch-unix.jar': Tag mismatch!
, response: 200 OK"

Comment: @N.K.T https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download

Comment: I have "Update & Restart" button. But it's giving me the error.

Comment: You are right. After updating studio, the error disappears! Thank you.

Comment: @N.K.T Glad to hear .Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are not running an OFFLINE WORK, in `settings> Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle` at the bottom, Offline work should not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

put `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'`

in build.gradle(Module:app) and sync the project.It should work fine without any errors

Comment: That's what I did & posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

The case also can be **proxy** too.
Disable proxy from `Settings > Appearance and behaviour > System Settings > Http proxy`
by checking `No Proxy` and also clear proxy lines from `gradle.properties (Global properties)` if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to declare `google()` in both `buildscripts` and `allobjects`

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha06'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your version to a newer version

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```