# Android Studio Giraffe - Upgrade to Hedgehog to the same folder not possible

Tags: android-studio, updates, windows-11

I am on Windows 11 (Enterprise) and I have Android Studio since some years.
I had not updated my Android Studio Giraffe (2022.3.1 Patch 2) for some month and now I see the update to Hedgehog (2023.1.1):

[image]

But when I download it (android-studio-2023.1.1.26-windows.exe) and try to install it, there is no way to upgrade the older Giraffe AS, I cannot install it in the same folder, I can only install it as a totally separate application:

[image]

Android Studio Setup - Please select an empty folder to install Android Studio

I found this thread here: [Can't update Android Studio - only download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980276/cant-update-android-studio-only-download/)
But the solutions there didnt help me in my case. With other search I was neither successful to find a hint what the issue could be.
I didnt find any clue that Giraffe and Hedgehog would be a separate installation.
I guess, this is some "homemade" issue, but what could it be?

Comment: Uninstall the old version and install the new version.

Comment: All my settings and projects will be kept?

Comment: As fas I remember yes. May be the unistaller asks. But it is always good to have a recent backup at hand.

Comment: Yes, this seems to have worked :) Uninstalling was not possible, no uninstaller present, but I renamed the folder, installed the new version in the original named folder and my projects and settings where still there. Even the AVDs are still present (the main thing for me). Thank you! I will write an answer about it with your name :)

Comment: The AVDs are always stored in the user home folder.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert (thank you!!!) posted in his comment of my question, I just had to uninstall the old version, and install the new version.

Uninstall was not possible, not via Windows settings (Apps > Installed Apps > Android Studio 1.0 > ... > Uninstall) and there was no uninstaller in the folder. But I just renamed the folder (`c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` to `c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio.bak`) and installed the new version to `c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\` and all my settings and my AVDs were still present.

I still don't know why there was no direct update possible but never mind, live and software goes on.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio there's uninstall.exe at the bottom. It gave me the option of keeping or deleting user settings. Then I installed the new version. Hope this helps in the future!

Comment: I didn't have that uninstall.exe, unfortunately.